# How to get the id of fill method in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I'm doing multi step form in Laravel, **belongsTo** relationships data is working, however in my pivot table it's not working because appointment_id is returning null. I want to get the id of `$app`.

```
        $app_service = new AppointmentService();

        $appointment = new Appointment();
        $app = $appointment->fill($validatedData);

        $app_service->fill(array(
            'appointment_id' => $app->id,
            'service_id' => $service_app
        ));

        $request->session()->put('app', $app);
```

Model Appointment

```
protected $fillable = ['clinic_id', 'doctor_id', 'patient_id', 'schedule_id', 'description', 'status', 'payment_option', 'start_time', 'end_time'];
```

AppointmentService is pivot table

```
protected $fillable = ['appointment_id', 'service_id'];
```

Comment: please post the information of all the tables

Comment: using fill is like temporary table, it's not saving to database. So how could I get the id the of inserted record.

Comment: What happend when you dd($app) variable?

is appointment_id mass assignable?

Comment: yes both uses fillable, I updated the question dd($app->id) is null

Comment: Why do you need to use the fill if you can just put the data in the session

Comment: how? I can put the other data in session but in pivot it returns as json

Comment: what do you mean json ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `fill()` you can just put the in the `session()` every step. Then insert them to database at the final step.

Example : User Account, User Information, and User Image. Let's say they are in separate model which I will call:

`User` - User Account

`Information` - User Information

`Image` - User Image.

Then let's say I already declare their relationship which is

`user()` -> For Information Model - BelongsTo

`information()` -> For User Model - HasOne

`image()` -> For User Model - HasOne

`user()` -> For Image model - BelongsTo

**1st Step**

```
// validation here

session(['information', $validatedUserInformation]); // store the validated data in the session

// redirect to next form
```

**2ndStep**

```
// validation here

session(['user', $validatedUserAccount]); // same as the first step store the 
validated data in the session

// redirect to next form
```

**The Last step**

```
// validation for image

//insert the parent table data
$user = User::create(
    session('user') // get the "user" data from the session
);

//insert the associated user information
$user->information()->create(
    session('information') // get the "information" data from the session
);

//insert the associated user image
$user->image()->create(
    $request->file('image')->store('image')
);
```